# Meta box does not save or update

Tags: metabox

Following is the code I used for metabox.

```
class my_metaboxes{


    public function __construct(){

        add_action('add_meta_boxes', array($this, 'my_overview_metabox'));
        add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'my_content_save'));
    }

    public function my_overview_metabox(){

        add_meta_box( 

            'page_overview_metabox', 
            'Page content overview', 
            array($this,'content_overview_metabox'), 
            'post', 
            'advanced', 
            'high' 
        );
    }

    public function content_overview_metabox($post){

        wp_nonce_field( 'content_overview_save', 'content_overview_nonce');
        $value=get_post_meta($post->ID, '_post_content_key', true);

        echo '<input type="text" id="page_content_overview_metabox" name="page_content_overview_metabox" value="'.esc_attr($value).'" placeholder="Enter the page overview details" style="width: 100%; height:120px;"';

    }

    public function my_content_save($post_id){

       if(!isset($_POST['content_overview_nonce'])){
            return;
       }

       if(!wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['content_overview_nonce'], 'my_content_save' )){
            return;
       }

       if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE){
            return;
       }

       if(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)){
            return;
       }

       if(!isset($_POST['page_content_overview_metabox'])){
            return;
       }

       $my_data= sanitize_text_field($_POST['page_content_overview_metabox']);

       update_post_meta( $post_id, '_post_content_key', $my_data);
    }
}
```

The metaboxes appear in the post section. However, I am not able to save the content entry.

Could someone please assist?

Thanks

Comment: you don't need to test the capabilitie `edit_post`, this test is already done before the hook "save_..." is fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the field is not saving is due to the nonce check in `my_content_save()` failing. Changing the nonce check to the following code will fix the issue:

```
if (!wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['content_overview_nonce'], 'content_overview_save' )){
    return;
}
```

The nonce check should use the `content_overview_save` action because that is what was specified here:

```
wp_nonce_field( 'content_overview_save', 'content_overview_nonce');
```

Note that there was also a missing `>` in the `#page_content_overview_metabox` input field. For the sake of completeness, here's the full updated code:

```
class my_metaboxes{

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'my_overview_metabox' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'my_content_save' ) );
    }

    public function my_overview_metabox(){
        add_meta_box( 
            'page_overview_metabox', 
            'Page content overview', 
            array( $this,'content_overview_metabox' ), 
            'post', 
            'advanced', 
            'high' 
        );
    }

    public function content_overview_metabox( $post ) {
        wp_nonce_field( 'content_overview_save', 'content_overview_nonce' );
        $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_post_content_key', true );

        echo '<input type="text" id="page_content_overview_metabox" name="page_content_overview_metabox" value="' . 
     esc_attr( $value ) . '" placeholder="Enter the page overview details" style="width: 100%; height:120px;">';

    }

    public function my_content_save( $post_id ){
       if ( ! isset($_POST['content_overview_nonce'])){
            return;
       }

       if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['content_overview_nonce'], 'content_overview_save' ) ) {
            return;
       }

       if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return;
       }

       if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
       }

       if ( !isset( $_POST['page_content_overview_metabox'] ) ) {
            return;
       }

       $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['page_content_overview_metabox'] );
       update_post_meta( $post_id, '_post_content_key', $my_data );
       }
}

new my_metaboxes();
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. I will quickly run to test it and come back. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Happy to help!